# Dark reflections on glass

Tags: rendering, transparency, glass

I have a building with a lot of glass, when i render i get this.[image]

The reflection on the glass its awfull.

I have a proper HDRI, and tried to just place lights and same result.
Some idea?

Comment: increase transparency bounces. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyXnE.png

Comment: Also note that glass needs to be thin sheet to look realistic, not a huge solid block.

Comment: @cegaton While that question is pertinent to the question, the question is asking about the glass *reflection*, which that doesn't help with.

Answer (score 0):

The reflection on the glass is awful because you don't have it enabled. Turn up the *Specular* parameter and adjust the *Roughness* to get the desired effect:

[image]